How to implement angled linear-gradient with color stops similar to CSS?
So I have the following CSS gradient example
background: var(--Gradient, linear-gradient(96deg, #FAF354 -11.84%, #00CA69 71.35%));

For Jetpack Compose I have only added colors, but I have no idea how to add such  angle (96deg) and color stops (-11.84%, 71.35%):
BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp)) {
    val size = with(LocalDensity.current) { maxHeight.toPx() }
    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(
                brush = Brush.linearGradient(
                    colors = listOf(
                        Color(0xFFFAF354),
                        Color(0xFF00CA69)
                    ),
                    start = Offset(...,...)
                    end = Offset(...,...)
                ),
            )
    )
}

Update:
Found solution for color stops:
 colorStops = arrayOf(
     Pair(-0.1184f /*-11.84f*/, Color(0xFFFAF354)),
     Pair(0.7135f /*71.35f*/, Color(0xFF00CA69))
 ),


To replicate a specific degree (e.g., 96deg) in Jetpack Compose for a gradient, you'll need to calculate the start and end offsets of the gradient based on trigonometry, using the specified degree.
Formula for Coordinates
To translate the degree into offsets:
start = Offset(0f, 0f) (gradient starts at the top-left corner)
end = Offset(width * cos(θ), height * sin(θ))

Where:
θ is the angle in radians (convert degrees to radians using
radians=degrees×/180radians=degrees×π/180).
width and height represent the size of the component.
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Brush
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.onSizeChanged
import kotlin.math.PI
import kotlin.math.cos
import kotlin.math.sin

@Composable
fun GradientWithDegrees(degree: Float = 96f) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .onSizeChanged { size ->
                // Calculate gradient end point based on the degree and size
                val radians = degree * PI.toFloat() / 180f
                val endX = size.width * cos(radians)
                val endY = size.height * sin(radians)

                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(
                            brush = Brush.linearGradient(
                                colors = listOf(
                                    Color(0xFFFAF354), // #FAF354
                                    Color(0xFF00CA69)  // #00CA69
                                ),
                                start = Offset(0f, 0f),
                                end = Offset(endX, endY)
                            )
                        )
                )
            }
    )
}

